# Find the pointwise limit of the sequence$f_n(x) = {1\over 1+x} + {2\over 1+x^2} + {4\over 1+x^4}+...+{2^n\over 1+x^{2^n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

$f_n:(1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is a sequence of functions defined by

$f_n(x) = {1\over 1+x} + {2\over 1+x^2} + {4\over 1+x^4}+...+{2^n\over 1+x^{2^n}}$

What is the pointwise limit of the sequence?

Since $x$ is greater than $1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}{2^n\over 1+x^{2^n}}=0$, so at least the sequence of function should have a limit. I want to first tackle the cases where n is finite, I tried to merge the terms in $f_n$ but do not know how to do it, or are there any better ways to make $f_n$ easier to analyze?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Note divergent for $|x|\le 1$.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry for the trouble, I didn't put on comments because I really have no constructive ideas about the problem.. thx for pointing out my problem

Comment: @herb steinberg yes! so the problem restricted the domain with $x\in (1, \infty)$

Comment: It's no trouble to me.  I just want you to have a good chance of getting your question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

I would recommend to start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{1 + x} + \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{2}{1-x^{2}} - \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}

Similarly, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{1-x^{2}} + \frac{2}{1+x^{2}} = \frac{4}{1 - x^{4}}
\end{align*}

and so on. So the proposed series is given by:
\begin{align*}
f_{n}(x) = \frac{2^{n+1}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}} - \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}

where $n\geq 0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $$f_{n}(x) = \frac{2^{n+1}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}-\frac{1}{1-x} ,n=0,1,2,\cdots.$$

Comment: @Riemann Thanks for pointing that out!